# How to prevent RecyclerView to auto scroll after layout calculation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view that has a horizontal linear layout manager, it has the strange behaviour of auto scroll to the first item when I'm scrolling it for the first time. Do you have any ideas on how to fix that?

I've already tried to use StaggeredLinearLayout, also tried to use fixed values for width and height, I tried to use         android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" also without success. So I ran out of ideas on how to fix it.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/bigItemsRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_normal"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            app:paddingInner="@dimen/margin_normal" />
```

I'd like to it not auto scroll, it uses an adapter with fixed items, so I don't need to call notify on data changed, it only happens once when I scroll to the next item. After this auto scroll, it stops happening.

Answer (score 0):

From the info above it's hard to tell what the problem is, but calling notifyDataSetChanged() when scrolling (if i understood you right) sounds like something you don't wanne do.

For example, if you scroll to item 1 and call notifyDataSetChanged. It will trigger a refresh and your recyclerView will scroll back to the first item.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, thats the thing I'm not calling notifyDataSetChanged(), I dont need to because the items on adapter don't change